# Updating Variant SKU

Tags: import, products, variants

I'm trying to update the variant SKUs of existing products. I'm using the supplier SKU field as a unique identifier, but I get this error every time I run the import. I'm only populating the SKU field and the supplierSKU field when importing.

Am I doing something wrong? What is the best way to update variant SKUs?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Guessing this is using the Feed Me plugin?